# I hate AJAX, what is the alternative

Tags: html, ajax, rich-internet-application

I really love AJAX, but sometimes this javascript/HTML/CSS combination makes me crazy. What alternative I have to create a rich engaging web administration panel (web application)?

I tried Adobe Flex, it seams cool, but its complexity is not to be underestimated.

What do you think?

Comment: I would have suggested Flex. Have you tried Silverlight?

Comment: "I hate AJAX", "I really love AJAX", ever talked to a psychiatrist about your dissociative identity disorder?

Comment: Flash, Silverlight, or Desktop App. Other than that, HTML/CSS/JavaScript is not as bad as you make it out to be (and is even more confusing because AJAX stands for Asynchronous Javascript And Xml, so I'm not sure where your issues are coming from).

Comment: @joni - you did not get the joke, did you :)

Comment: OK, all the same, Flex, Silverlight, jQuery... aren't some new and innovative technologies out there? Where I can create an app fast and painless.

Comment: There is no magic button that you click and it gives you exactly what you want.  (There are wizards for some things, but I consider them evil.)

Answer (score 2):

Out of the technologies, I would think that HTML, CSS, and JavaScript would be the least confusing.  HTML and CSS are very easy to grasp.  JavaScript takes a little more effort, but using a library such as jQuery simplifies it quite a bit.